# Chamar um Classe pelo javascript/Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

É possível carregar um método específico a partir de um ajax ? Vou dar um exemplo:

```
var actions  = {
    options : {
        action  : "newPost" ,
        dados   : {
                  title     : "Novo Post"   ,
                  content   : "Conteúdo"  ,
                  author    : "Autor" 
        }
    },
    init : function() {
        var _this = this;
        $.ajax({
            url         : "action.php" ,
            method      : "POST" ,
            dataType    : "json" ,
            date        : _this.action ,
            success     : function(action){
                console.log(action);
            }
        });
    }
}
action.init();



class Action{
    public $_action;

    public newPost($title , $content , $user){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução seria um endereço específico que chamasse um método especifico que você necessita. Exemplo:

Arquivos:

`index.php`: onde vamos fazer a chamada ajax;

`ActionClass.php`: Sua classe Action;

`action.php`: Arquivo onde será executado a action;

```
//index.php
var actions = {
  options: {
   action: "newPost",
    dados: {
      title: "Novo Post",
      content: "Conteúdo",
      author: "Autor"
    }
  },
  init: function() {
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      date: {action:_this.action},
      success: function(action) {
        console.log(action);
      }
    });
  }
}
action.init();
```

```
//ActionClass.php
class Action{
    public $_action;

    public newPost($title , $content , $user){

    }
}
```

```
//action.php
include "ActionClass.php";

$action = new Action();

$act = $_POST['action'];

if($act == 'newPost'){
  $action->newPost([...]);
}else if($act == 'deletePost'){
  $action->deletePost();               
}
```